# How do I modify this conditional statement to get my desired output?

Tags: conditionals

In the code below, I want only the line **Text goes here...** to remain in the output when I comment the line `\articlehistory{Physics}{07/06/2022}{28/06/2022}`. How do I do this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\articlehistory}[3]{%
\def\type{#1}%
\def\recieved{#2}%
\def\accepted{#3}%
}

\makeatletter
\let\type=\@empty
\let\recieved=\@empty
\let\accepted=\@empty

\def\@setarticlehistory{%
Article type: \type;
Recieved: \recieved;
Accepted: \accepted.
}
\makeatother
\articlehistory{Physics}{07/06/2022}{28/06/2022}
\begin{document}
Text goes here...

\makeatletter
\ifx\@empty\articlehistory\else\@setarticlehistory\fi
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want

```
\ifx\@empty\accepted
```

as it is the three inner commands that have conditional definition,
`\ifx\@empty\articlehistory`
is always false as `\articlehistory` has a fixed non-empty definition